# Remove a <li> when pressing a span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fadeOut some `<li>`, but without luck. Check my code bellow:

```
<li class="lclass" id="1">
    First Li
    <span class="removeit" id="1" style="color:#C00;">Remove</span>
</li>
<li class="lclass" id="2">
    First Li
    <span class="removeit" id="2" style="color:#C00;">Remove</span>
</li>
<li class="lclass" id="3">
    First Li
    <span class="removeit" id="3" style="color:#C00;">Remove</span>
</li>
```

With my code, only the `span class="removeit"` fades out. I want to fade out the whole div when i am press the remove button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.removeit').click(function () {
        $(this).hide("fast");   
    });
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: As a side note, your IDs must be unique

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `.parent()` or `.closest('li')` to get parent li and then hide the whole object.like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.removeit').click(function () {
     $(this).parent().hide("fast");  //or $(this).closest('li').hide("fast");
   });
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JQR9f/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)** or **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** to get the parent `li` element in your case then you can use `fadeOut` to fade out the matching `li`:

```
$('.removeit').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('li').fadeOut();   
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wWBCR/)**

---

Also, you should use class instead of id because `id` is unique:

```
<li class="lclass 1">
<span class="removeit 1" style="color:#C00;">
```

Besides that, number is not a valid `id`, you can use `li1`,`li2`, `span1`, `span2`... instead:

```
<li class="lclass span1">
<span class="removeit span1" style="color:#C00;">
```